Exercise 9.1 in Introduction to stochastic processes by Lawler
This is not for any assignment or homework. I am studying Chapter 9, Stochastic Integration, in Introduction to Stochastic Processes by Lawler. Exercise 9.1 states

Since I am self-studying, I'm uncertain about the accuracy of my attempt at part b) below. Could someone proficient in stochastic calculus provide feedback on my writing? I appreciate any assistance. Thank you.


Is $exp{\int _0^t F(R_s)ds}$ a function of $t$ or $R_t$? This gave me a headache. What is its  derivative w.r.t $R_t$? I can't find answer from Lawler's book. Can anyone give some directions or any book that I can read?

I realized the process above is wrong.
Note that
$$d(\int_0^t F(R_s)ds)=\int_0^{t+dt} F(R_s)ds-\int_0^t F(R_s)ds=F(R_t)dt.$$
Let $K=exp\{\int_0^t F(R_s)ds\})$. Notice that the order of covariation term $d \langle R, K\rangle _t$ is $dt\cdot dW_t$, which is higher than $dt$.
Now apply the product rule and obtain
$$d(R_t\cdot K)=K\cdot dR_t+R_t\cdot dK\\
=K\cdot dR_t+R_t \cdot K\cdot d(\int_0^t F(R_s)ds)= K\cdot dR_t+R_t \cdot K\cdot F(R_t)dt$$
From part a), we know that $dR_t =f(R_t)dt+g(R_t)dW_t$. The drift above becomes
$$K\cdot[f(R_t)+R_t\cdot F(R_t)]dt$$
Hence, the answer should be $F(R_t)=-\frac{f(R_t)}{R_t}$.
